# Do const generics and the `typenum` crate have an overlapping purpose?

Tags: generics, rust, types, constants, const-generics

After learning about const generics and stumbling upon the [`typenum`](https://docs.rs/typenum/latest/typenum/) crate, I was confused by the fact that they seem to have an overlapping purpose - using numeric values as a type.

The only difference is that `typenum` provides more flexibility, such as arithmetic operations on the number types, but with less intuitive and ergonomic usage. `typenum` existed before const generics, and many of the features from `typenum` seem to be undergoing discussion to be added in the const generic syntax.

I couldn't find anything explaining the relation between these two, but all the things above is leading me to the conclusion:
**"`typenum` is a bandage fix to the current limitations of const generics".**

Is this correct? Is there more to `typenum` that is beyond the scope of const generics, or will it be eventually completely replaced by const generics once its features and syntaxes are more mature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, and was even more correct before the introduction of `min_const_generics`, where not only arithmetic operations but also all of const generics was not available. Back then `typenum` (combined with [`generic-array`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/) was really useful. Today it is less useful, but due to the limitations in `min_const_generics` some uses still require it. Hopefully, in the future it won't be needed at all.